# Retain Cycle Even when using Weak/Strong ARC Semantics

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

`I admit that I am not an expert on ARC and retain cycles though through some research and some great articles (like [this](http://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/)), I believe I get the basics.

However, I am currently stumped. I have a property defined as follows.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) Foo *foo;
```

Inside my `init`, I do the following.

```
if(self = [super init]) {

    _foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

    // async the rest
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {

        __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

        if (strongSelf.foo != nil) {
                        [strongSelf.foo runTests];
        }
    });
}
return self;
}
```

and here is my dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {
     _foo = nil;
}
```

If the `dispatch_aync` block is commented out, I see my Foo `dealloc` get called immediately after foo is set to `nil`. With the block commented in, foo's `delloc` is not called.

I've got a retain cycle correct? Any idea how?

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest using `strong` instead of `retain` in your definition of the `Foo` property. There's little practical impact in this case, but in ARC code, you should be using `strong` and `weak`, not `retain` and `assign`. Also, in ARC code, you no longer need to manually `nil` your instance variables, so you can retire that `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not necessarily have a retain cycle (now known as a "strong reference cycle" in ARC). You have code that, if `foo` existed by the time `strongSelf` was defined, `foo` will be retained until the dispatched code finishes.

The only potential strong reference cycle here is the `delegate` you passed to `foo`. If that `delegate` is defined as `strong` property of the `Foo` class, then you have a strong reference cycle. If it's defined as a `weak` property, then you have no strong reference cycle.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, once the `delegate` is property made `weak`, there is no need for the posted `dealloc` method nor is there any need for the `__weak self` use in the dispatch block.

Comment: The `dealloc` method can be removed in ARC regardless. If the `delegate` was `weak`, it's just not necessary. If the `delegate` was `strong`, you have a strong reference cycle (bad, bad, bad) and the `dealloc` would never get called, anyway (!).

Comment: Thanks for all the great input, I'm learning a ton here. So the delegate property of Foo is defined as `(nonatomic, assign)`. This code base was migrated too `ARC`, I think that's why we have the older property attributes.

Comment: It means `__unsafe_unretained`, which means that it won't retain the object, but will leave a dangling pointer if the object is deallocated. That's why `weak` is so much better, that that pointer will be set to `nil` when the `delegate` is released, thereby eliminating whole categories of types of crashes. Replace that `assign` with `weak`.

Comment: @Rob by the way the reason I'm even chasing this is I'm relying on `foo` to be set to nil in dealloc to trigger `Foo`'s dealloc which sets the `delegate` to nil. What I'm seeing is an async operation inside `foo` completes after the `dealloc`. Then inside the completion block I call on the `delegate` and of course get an access violation.

Comment: @Ternary No. When this object is released, it will automatically release its strong reference to `foo` anyway. Your `dealloc` was appropriate in pre-ARC code, but ARC eliminates the need for that `dealloc` method, and it's entirely redundant. Won't hurt, but should be removed in ARC to simplify your code. BTW, if that dispatch block is still running, the dispatch block, itself, will retain `foo`, so whether you `nil` it in `dealloc` or not, there is still one strong reference cycle (the dispatch block) that will keep it around.

Comment: If you want `foo` to be stopped and deallocated when this object is released, you have to implement your own cancellation logic within `foo`, which you can call from `dealloc`. A common pattern is to implement a `cancel` method which you'd call from `dealloc`. You'd then have `runTests` check frequently to see if `foo` was cancelled, and if so, terminate the tests immediately and return (thus ending the dispatch block and resolving that remaining strong reference).

Comment: @Rob great explanation, I see the benefits of the `weak` now. Will test now and report back. Will this be easier with swift? :)

Comment: Changed my delegate to `(atomic, weak)` and when the async operation complete the delegate is already `nil`'d. *Beautiful*. I also changed `foo` to be `(atomic, strong)`. I think I'm good!

Comment: So in my case, did I even need that weak/strong stuff anyway or should that always be the default? Seems like just lots of extra code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60992/discussion-between-rob-and-ternary).